# JS to validate a form on clicking submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, angularjs

I am a newb to js and I have prepared a form using angular JS an JQuery.The code is as follows:

```
<form id="frm1" onsubmit="return null()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="fname" name="fname" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="Lname" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email ID:</td>
      <td><input type="email" ng-model="mailid" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" ng-model="pass" required></td><br/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" ng-model="Cpass" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" ng-model="Cpass" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address:</td>
      <td><textarea ng-model="address" required></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="reset" onclick="formReset()"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="submit"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="formClose()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And the Script fot the above form is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.button-submit').click(function() {
      $("#magic").show();
    });
  });  

  function formReset()
  {
    document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
  }

  function formClose()
  {
    $("#magic").hide();
  }

  function null()
  {
    var x=document.forms["frm1"]["fname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") 
    {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

The Reset and the close button work absolutely fine but he problem is that the Submit button validation is not working properly. Right now I am just trying to validate the fname field and it is not working for me. I cannot figure out the exact reason for this. Can anyone please try and help me to get past this problem.

Comment: I tried in console which didn't allow me use 'null' as it is a keyword. try another name.

Comment: Why did you choose to use jQuery instead of Angular to perform this validation? Angular has mechanisms for handling form submission and you can use your data bindings to easily validate the form data before handling a submission to a server.

Comment: @izuriel While using the angular js the message displayed is please fill out the required field but I wand to display the message "First name required" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of problems with the code.

1. Never name a variable or a function with a javascript keyword. In this case `null`
2. For `onsubmit` event to work, `submit` button's type should be `submit` not `button`.
3. You already have `required` field in `fname` field and you are still trying to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dude, Use Validate Plugin for Validation
 Example:
  $(".selector").validate({
 rules: {
// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
name: "required",
// compound rule
email: {
  required: true,
  email: true
     }
       }
},
  messages: {
name: "Please specify your name",
email: {
  required: "We need your email address to contact you",
  email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
}
```

}
       });
    [Validate Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)